# Blank lines in python bytecode

Tags: python, virtual-machine, bytecode

When once disassembles a python function using the `dis` function, there are blank lines between some opcodes as shown below.

```
  >>> dis(fizzbuzz)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 BINARY_MODULO
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       36
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 (5)
             22 BINARY_MODULO
             23 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             26 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             29 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       36

  3          32 LOAD_CONST               4 ('FizzBuzz')
             35 RETURN_VALUE

  4     >>   36 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             39 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
             42 BINARY_MODULO
             43 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             46 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             49 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       56

  5          52 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Fizz')
             55 RETURN_VALUE

  6     >>   56 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             59 LOAD_CONST               3 (5)
             62 BINARY_MODULO
             63 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             66 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             69 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       76

  7          72 LOAD_CONST               6 ('Buzz')
             75 RETURN_VALUE

  9     >>   76 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (str)
             79 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             82 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             85 RETURN_VALUE
             86 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             89 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `>>` are used to indicate labelled instructions but I don't seem to get what the blank lines are for. Has anyone got any idea what these blank lines signify?

Answer (score 1):

The blank lines are breaks between disassemblies of statements. The numbers at the front of the first lines of the block are the line numbers of the source, assuming you have them.

For instance:

```
def test():
    x = 1
    y = 2
```

will show up as

```
2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
            3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
            9 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
```

Where the 2 and 3 refer to lines 2 and 3 of the original source.